# Importing neo4j database into Gephi - there are no labels

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I have a neo4j database (2.0.3) I have used the [neo4j gephi plugin](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/neo4j-graph-database-support/) to import it into Gephi.

It mostly works, however when I go to the 'data labratory' in Gephi all of the information is there except the 'Label' column is blank for all entries. Is this a known issue? Or is there any way to resolve this? I can't seem to find this issue anywhere else online. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. Currently node labels are ignored by the gephi neo4j plugin. I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/pull/47) to include them as a new neo4j_node_label column of type list_string. Note: gephi's neo4j plugin will try to upgrade your database to 2.1.0 when importing it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. This functionality would definitely be useful.  Thanks for the tip as well. I did discover that error the hardway and now I only import a secondary datastore into Gephi when I need it.